# Ng serve not working after uninstalling a package

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-bootstrap

> Can you guys help me on how I can run `ng serve` again successfully.

I worked on an Angular project that used **Bootstrap**, and then I installed **Angular Material**, my design was ruined. So, I tried to uninstall Angular Material using `npm uninstall @angular/material` and it turned out that it got uninstalled successfully. I closed my running server `localhost:4200` and then tried to run the project again using `ng serve` but it gave me this error `An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\desktop\github_repos\library-management-system\node_modules\@angular\material' See "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-XYBGzp\angular-errors.log" for further details.`

Follow up question: Does **Bootstrap** and **Angular Material** cannot work together?

Thank you!

> And this is the contents inside the `angular-errors.log` file:

````
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1800:7)
    at resolveGlobalStyles (D:\desktop\github_repos\library-management-system\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\styles.js:54:31)
    at Object.getStylesConfig (D:\desktop\github_repos\library-management-system\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\styles.js:87:70)
    at D:\desktop\github_repos\library-management-system\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:153:23
    at generateWebpackConfig (D:\desktop\github_repos\library-management-system\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:59:49)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async generateBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (D:\desktop\github_repos\library-management-system\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:116:20)
    at async Object.generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (D:\desktop\github_repos\library-management-system\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:66:20)
    at async setup (D:\desktop\github_repos\library-management-system\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:149:47)```
````

Comment: Just remove node modules and try to install them again without material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not using any Angular Material in your code. And check the package.json if `@angular/material` is deleted from the dependecies list, then run ‘ npm install ‘

Comment: I did not use any angular material but i found out that the problem was in the app.module.ts, i forgot to delete the angular/material imports there.

Comment: Good to hear you solved your problem! with 'Make sure you are not using any Angular Material in your code' I meant also import statements of Angular Material @SED